# Is there a single word to indicate someone with a migraine?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

You can say "people with a migraine", or "someone with a migraine", but is there a single word to express that concept as an adjective? Like, instead of saying "someone suffering from schizophrenia" we just say "schizophrenic".

Comment: For the more inclusive "headache" you can call someone "headachy".  Let's invent "migrainiac" for someone with a migraine.

Comment: A migrainiac seems more like someone who likes migraines to me :)

Comment: (Commenting from the review queue: I'm voting to leave this question open because the form of the requested word has been conveyed in the sample sentence.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a noun, the word is [*migraineur*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/migraineur), from the French for a sufferer of migraines. The ngram viewer finds the word in print in a 1936 issue of [*The Yale Journal of Biology and Medicine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RvoqAAAAIAAJ&q=%22migraineur%22&dq=%22migraineur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKg9mF_6vOAhXBPCYKHXe8CG44ChDoAQgvMAU):

> If the physical examination of a **migraineur** reveals any
>   objectively evident defects they should be remedied as far as
>   possible; not with the promise of curing the migraine but with the
>   object of ameliorating the condition

If you're looking for an adjective, the word is *migrainous*, which the *OED* attests from 1889, giving examples that modify the disease. But modern usage applies the word to people. From [*Migraine: Manifestations, Pathogenesis, and Management*](https://books.google.com/books?id=esBrAAAAMAAJ&q=%22migrainous%20patient%22&dq=%22migrainous%20patient%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv79TJgKzOAhVI7SYKHTv4BOcQ6AEIHjAA) by R A Davidoff:

> It is important to determine the average frequency of attacks for each
>   patient, because changes in the frequency of migraine attacks may
>   indicate the development of an intracranial lesion in a previously
>   **migrainous** patient.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest , from the [medical dictionnary online](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/)

> [Cephalalgic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cephalalgic)
>
> adj relating to or affected by headache

This adjective built the same way as schizophrenic, except that because it's a bit rarer the noun form does not mean a patient suffering from migraine but:

> n a headache-relieving medicine

See examples of usage, extracted from [Gbook](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=cephalalgic#q=cephalalgic&tbm=bks&start=10)

> The second publication reports on results obtained in 32 chronic
> **cephalalgic students**.
>
> In post-menopausal **cephalalgic women** Facchinetti et al. observed ...
>
> **Cephalalgic population** has been divided into three groups: Group A: 58

The word comes from

> Cephalalgia
>
> Etymology: Gk, kephale, head, algos, pain headache,
>
> often combined
> with another word to indicate a specific type of headache, such as
> histamine cephalalgia. Also called cephalea, cephalgia. See also
> histamine headache.

It's sometimes spelt (mispelt?) *Cephalgic*, see examples from [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=cephalgic%20)

As a bonus the earliest use in a medical reference is in The American Journal of [the Medical Science](https://books.google.ca/books?id=dW1DAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA396&dq=cephalalgic&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=cephalalgic&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  Unlike schizophrenia, there is no specific adjective for the person who suffers from that condition. **"Migrainous"** is an adjective but you never say "a migrainous woman" or a "migrainous subject".  A **"migrainous attack"** and **"a migraine patient"** are current usage, though.

There is also the adjective "hemicranic" (**hemicrania**, a hemicranic type of headache, **is a medical term for migraine**) but it doesn't refer to people.

Comment: Huh, I wondered if "hemicraniac" would work (like "maniac," "insomniac") but it doesn't seem to exist.